# Слово «тать» произошло от немецкого «Täter»?

Tags: этимология

Правда ли, что слово **тать** является калькой с немецкого ***Täter***?

Answer (score 2):

Не от немецкого. Праславянские истоки у слова "тать".

[Этимология](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

> Происходит от праслав. *tatь, от кот. в числе прочего произошли:
>   др.-русск. тать, ст.-слав. тать (κλέπτης; Остром., Супр.), сербохорв.
>   та̑т (род. п. та̏та), словенск. tȃt (род. п. tа̑tа, tatû). Праслав.
>   основа на -i, родственная др.-ирл. tāid м. «вор» (*tātis), греч. τητάω
>   «лишаю», дор. τᾱτάω — то же. Далее связано с тайный, таю́, таить.

[Факсмер](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-13341.htm) подтверждает (с подробностями).